# How to Read a csv file and save in SQL Server Without change the characters

Tags: sql-server, csv, character-encoding

My file has some like this:
123;45;São Paulo;Brasil...

But, when I read from a C# program, then I send the value 'São Paulo' to SQL Server it is changed to 'S?o Paulo'.

How can I avoid this bad "translation"?

Thanks your effort.

...
Hi, people. Sorry for my lack of information.
Let me write again:

- I know the source file is ok: as I open it with notepad so with
  ms-word the characters set is ok... São Paulo IS São Paulo!!
- My code read the source using FileStream() and I, know that the
  variable that hold the buffer read show the correct: São Paulo IS
  São Paulo!!
- Than I builded a SQL expression to use in a command, a little bit like:

`...
    comm.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE Customer SET CityFrom = '{0}'", vBuff[2]);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

- Again, I just verify the property CommandText and the values are 100% ok.

... After all, I use Micrososft SSMS to verify the record: in this momment the field is shown as 'S?o Paulo', despite my SQL field be a nvarchar(100).

Comment: what's the data type you are using? i'd expect nvarchar to fix this--also what's the collation of the database?

Comment: Try to isolate the step the problem is: reading, storing, retrieving or displaying. Before reading a text file, you have to know the character encoding. Please [edit] to show your C# code, DML SQL (query) and DDL SQL (table).

Comment: Continuing to check up through the storage step: What does this give `SELECT TOP(1) CityFrom, CAST(CityFrom AS VARBINARY) FROM Customer;` ?

Comment: Hi, Tom. Thanks your attention.  
This command returns '0x53003F004F0020005000410055004C004F00' to words 'S?O PAULO'